# Need help on Regex to include European accents and special characters

Tags: regex

There are tons of articles here around but I wasn't able to find a solution in this case.

I need to **exclude any strings that doesn't include European characters** like Chinese, Arabic, Russian etc.

Is is possible with **one single Regex** to match:

- **Alphanumeric** Latin Characters (`a,b,c,1,2,3,A,B,C ...`)
- European **Accents** (`è,é,ò,ç,à ...`)
- UTF-8 **Symbols** (`© ...`)
- **Currencies** (`€,£,$ ...`)
- Whitespaces

And exclude all other characters?

Comment: It would be better if you have a few samples of what you're trying to match and what you're trying to exclude.

Comment: @ThomasAyoub at the end of the question there is a list of what I like to match...against I wish to exclude anything else like chinese arabic etc. Or the inverse (match all chinese, arabic etc. and exclude what is there in my list).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you'll need is something like:

```
[\p{Sc}\p{So}\p{Mn}\p{P}\p{Z}À-ÿ\w]
```

Here:

- `\p{Sc}` matches any currency sign
- `\p{So}` matches Various symbols that are not math symbols, currency signs, or combining characters
- `\p{Mn}` matches a character intended to be combined with another character without taking up extra space (e.g. accents, umlauts, etc.)
- `\p{P}` matches any kind of punctuation character
- <strike>`\p{L}` matches any kind of letter from any language</strike>
- `\p{Z}` matches any kind of whitespace or invisible separator
- `À-ÿ` matches accents
- `\w` any alphanum

Comment: Thanks, is it possible to match also `=` and `+` ?